# Building a Shiny app with an HTML template

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm trying to build a Shiny app using an HTML template, as specified in the [docs](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/templates.html). I'm using Bulma as the CSS framework, and because the app has many graphics I've decided to use tabs to separate them.

The output (some `renderText` in this example) is showing correctly in the first tab, but in the second tab the output isn't showing, only the `selectInput` and I can't see any error messages in the console. Below a reproducible example of what I'm trying to accomplish and some images to illustrate.

I suspect that I may be missing an additional code (JavaScript maybe?) to tell shiny to display the output in the second tab, but if so, why is the selectInput shown and not the `textOuptut`? Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

#### template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Shiny app</title>
  {{ headContent() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="hero is-danger is-bold is-small">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="container has-text-centered">
        <h1 class="title">
          Example Shiny app
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-foot">
      <nav class="tabs is-boxed is-centered">
        <div class="container">
          <ul>
            <li class="tab is-active" onclick="openTab(event,'Tab1')"><a>Tab 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab" onclick="openTab(event,'Tab2')"><a>Tab 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab" onclick="openTab(event,'Tab3')"><a>Tab 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section main">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="Tab1" class="content-tab">
        <p>
          tab1<br>
          Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
          PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <div>
          {{ select }}
        </div>
        <div>
          {{ text }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Tab2" class="content-tab" style="display:none">
        <p>
          tab2<br>
          Details Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
          industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
          scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
        <div>
          {{ select2 }}
        </div>
        <div>
          {{ text2 }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Tab3" class="content-tab" style="display:none">
        <p>
          tab3 <br>
          It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
          and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
          PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

#### server.R

```
library(shiny)

function(input, output) {
  
  output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", input$var)
  })
  
  output$selected_var2 <- renderText({ 
    paste("You have selected", input$var2)
  })

}
```

#### ui.R

```
htmlTemplate("template.html",
             select = selectInput("var", 
                                  label = "Choose a variable to display",
                                  choices = c("Percent White", 
                                              "Percent Black",
                                              "Percent Hispanic", 
                                              "Percent Asian"),
                                  selected = "Percent White"),
             
             text = textOutput("selected_var"),
             
             select2 = selectInput("var2", 
                                   label = "Choose a variable to display",
                                   choices = c("Choice one", 
                                               "Choice two",
                                               "Choice three", 
                                               "Choice four"),
                                   selected = "Percent White"),
             
             text2 = textOutput("selected_var2")
)
```

#### index.js (javascript to open the tabs)

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, x, tablinks;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("content-tab");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" is-active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " is-active";
  }
```

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

Comment: JavaScript seems to be fine. May be some think with R files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need to call `Shiny.unbindAll()` before removing Shiny inputs/outputs from the page, and `Shiny.bindAll()` after adding Shiny inputs/outputs to the page.

Usually Shiny adds and removes inputs/outputs to the page itself, and ensures that those inputs/outputs are properly initialized and hooked up to Shiny (also known as "binding"). When you add or remove inputs/outputs outside of Shiny, you have to let Shiny know using `Shiny.unbindAll()` and `Shiny.bindAll()`.

For example, in the `openTab` function in `index.js`:

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, x, tablinks;

    Shiny.unbindAll();

    x = document.getElementsByClassName("content-tab");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" is-active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " is-active";

    Shiny.bindAll();
}
```

`bindAll()` and `unbindAll()` search the entire page by default, but you can also call them on a specific element such as the tab content:

```
function openTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, x, tablinks, activetab;

    x = document.getElementsByClassName("content-tab");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        Shiny.unbindAll(x[i]);
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" is-active", "");
    }
    activetab = document.getElementById(tabName)
    activetab.style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " is-active";
    Shiny.bindAll(activetab);
}
```

For more info, see https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html#use-javascript-to-modify-the-page and https://community.rstudio.com/t/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-shiny-bindall/14489/2

Comment: Thank you @gregL! Now I understand better what I was missing and the app is working.